# http status 404 error while using acl path beg in haproxy?

Tags: http, haproxy

I want to this using HAProxy only.  I have the Tomcat homepage running on http://206.189.22.155:30000/.  Here 206.189.22.155 is the IP address of my Ubuntu server.  I used the following HAProxy configuration to map it to the URL http://206.189.22.155/page-designer.

**haproxy.cfg**

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
        #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http-in
    mode    http

    bind 206.189.22.155:80

    acl path-page-designer              path_beg -i /page-designer
    use_backend page-designer-backend   if path-page-designer

backend page-designer-backend
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor

    server  appserver1 206.189.22.155:30000
```

But why am I getting a HTTP status 404 error /page-designer whenever I hit the URL http://206.189.22.155/page-designer? I need to map this to be able to see the Tomcat homepage at http://206.189.22.155/page-designer.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because /page-desinger is being passed to the backend server, and there is no /page-desinger folder or file.
You need to remove that path when sending the request to the backend.
There are various forms to accomplish this, depending on your HAProxy version, do a:
# haproxy -v 
on bash and let us know the version